# Why is my local storage resetting on every refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

```
export default function App() {
    const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState(sampleRes)

    useEffect(() => {
        const savedRecipe = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(RECIPE_ID));
        if (savedRecipe) setRecipes(savedRecipe)
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(RECIPE_ID, JSON.stringify(recipes))
    }, [recipes])
```

Comment: Debugging 101: add console.log()s to find  out what is called and when

Comment: because the state `recipes` is being set on mount, the second useEffect is called setting local storage again

Answer (score 1):

recipes is empty when app is mounted, so it is undefined.
And since useEffect runs after this event, your localstorage item will be set to undefined.
So add a check to verify if recipes is undefined before setting it on local storage.